# Cross-platform up- and downgradable read/write lock

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14

I try to turn some central data structure of a large codebase multithreaded.
The access interfaces were changed to represent read/write locks, which may be up- and downgraded:

**Before:**

```
Container& container = state.getContainer();
auto value = container.find( "foo" )->bar;
container.clear();
```

**Now:**

```
ReadContainerLock container = state.getContainer();
auto value = container.find( "foo" )->bar;
{
  // Upgrade read lock to write lock
  WriteContainerLock write = state.upgrade( container );
  write.clear();
} // Downgrades write lock to read lock
```

Using an actual `std::mutex` for the locking (instead of r/w implementation) works fine but brings no performance benefit (actually degrades runtime).

Actual changing data is relatively rare, so it seems very desirable to go with the read/write concept. The big issue now is that I cannot seem to find any library, which implements the read/write concept and supports upgrade and downgrade and works on Windows, OSX and Linux alike.

*Boost* has `BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_SHARED_MUTEX_UPWARDS_CONVERSIONS` but does not seem to support <strike>downgrading</strike> (blocking) atomic upgrading from `shared` to `unique`.

Is there any library out there, that supports the desired feature set?

**EDIT:**

Sorry for being unclear. Of course I mean multiple-readers/single-writer lock semantic.

Comment: Fwiw, here is a C++ standards paper proposing what you're asking for:  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3427.html  The committee took the read/write part but not the up/down-gradable part.

Comment: What semantics?  If any read lock can upgrade, you need to be able to back out of other reads to prevent deadlocks when two threads, both with read lock, upgrade to write.  Or you need to restrict to only one read lock, which is dumb.  Or a write lock does not prevent other read locks, also dumb.  I ask this because your code sample says "read lock" not "upgradable lock".

Comment: You just fundamentally changed the question.  <s>downgrading</s> is not the same as "atomic upgrading from `shared` to `unique`".  If you asked the wrong question, ask another question instead of changing the one you asked.  I provided a comprehensive answer to the problem "I want downgrades", but then you said "oh, I didn't mean *downgrades*, I meant a specific *upgrade*".

Comment: @Yakk, sorry if you feel this way, but the title already says up/downgrading, so does the rest of the text. I only corrected my perception, that **Boost** was not providing downgrading (which was wrong).

Comment: @abergmeier Understood.  You want a general purpose read lock with the ability to upgrade any read lock to write lock.  This is not possible, I'll illustrate below.

Answer (score 4):

The question has changed since I answered.  As the previous answer is still useful, I will leave it up.

The new question seems to be "I want a (general purpose) reader writer lock where any reader can be upgraded to a writer atomically".

This cannot be done without deadlocks, or the ability to roll back operations (transactional reads), which is far from general-purpose.

Suppose you have Alice and Bob.  Both want to read for a while, then they both want to write.

Alice and Bob both get a read lock.  They then upgrade to a write lock.  Neither can progress, because a write lock cannot be acquired while a read lock is acquired.  You cannot unlock the read lock, because then the state Alice read while read locked may not be consistent with the state after the write lock is acquired.

This can only be solved with the possibility the read->write upgrade can fail, or the ability to rollback all operations in a read (so Alice can "unread", Bob can advance, then Alice can re-read and try to get the write lock).

Writing type-safe transactional code isn't really supported in C++.  You can do it manually, but beyond simple cases it is error prone.  Other forms of transactional rollbacks can also be used.  None of them are general purpose reader-writer locks.

Answer (score 2):

You can roll your own.  If the states are R, U, W and {} (read, upgradable, write and no lock), these are transitions you can easily support:

```
{} -> R|U|W
R|U|W -> {}
U->W
W->U
U->R
```

and implied by the above:

```
W->R
```

which I think satisifies your requirements.

The "missing" transition is `R->U`, which is what lets us have multiple-readers safely.  At most one reader (the upgrade reader) has the right to upgrade to write without releasing their read lock.  While they are in that upgrade state they do not block other threads from reading (but they do block other threads from writing).

---

Here is a sketch.  There is a `shared_mutex A;` and a `mutex B;`.

`B` represents the right to upgrade to write *and* the right to read while you hold it.  All writers also hold a `B`, so you cannot both have the right to upgrade to write while someone else has the right to write.

Transitions look like:

```
 {}->R = read(A)
 {}->W = lock(B) then write(A)
 {}->U = lock(B)
 U->W = write(A)
 W->U = unwrite(A)
 U->R = read(A) then unlock(B)
 W->R = W->U->R
 R->{} = unread(A)
 W->{} = unwrite(A) then unlock(B)
 U->{} = unlock(B)
```

This simply requires `std::shared_mutex` and `std::mutex`, and a bit of boilerplate to write up the locks and the transitions.

If you want to be able to spawn a write lock while the upgrade lock "remains in scope" extra work needs to be done to "pass the upgrade lock back to the read lock".

Here are some bonus try transitions, inspired by @HowardHinnat below:

```
R->try U = return try_lock(B) && unread(A)
R->try W = return R->try U->W
```

Here is an upgradable_mutex with no try operations:

```
struct upgradeable_mutex {
  std::mutex u;
  std::shared_timed_mutex s;

  enum class state {
    unlocked,
    shared,
    aspiring,
    unique
  };

  // one step at a time:
  template<state start, state finish>
  void transition_up() {
    transition_up<start, (state)((int)finish-1)>();
    transition_up<(state)((int)finish-1), finish>();
  }
  // one step at a time:
  template<state start, state finish>
  void transition_down() {
    transition_down<start, (state)((int)start-1)>();
    transition_down<(state)((int)start-1), finish>();
  }

  void lock();
  void unlock();
  void lock_shared();
  void unlock_shared();
  void lock_aspiring();
  void unlock_aspiring();
  void aspiring_to_unique();
  void unique_to_aspiring();
  void aspiring_to_shared();
  void unique_to_shared();
};
template<>
void upgradeable_mutex::transition_up<
  upgradeable_mutex::state::unlocked, upgradeable_mutex::state::shared
>
() {
  s.lock_shared();
}
template<>
void upgradeable_mutex::transition_down<
  upgradeable_mutex::state::shared, upgradeable_mutex::state::unlocked
>
() {
  s.unlock_shared();
}
template<>
void upgradeable_mutex::transition_up<
  upgradeable_mutex::state::unlocked, upgradeable_mutex::state::aspiring
>
() {
  u.lock();
}
template<>
void upgradeable_mutex::transition_down<
  upgradeable_mutex::state::aspiring, upgradeable_mutex::state::unlocked
>
() {
  u.unlock();
}
template<>
void upgradeable_mutex::transition_up<
  upgradeable_mutex::state::aspiring, upgradeable_mutex::state::unique
>
() {
  s.lock();
}
template<>
void upgradeable_mutex::transition_down<
  upgradeable_mutex::state::unique, upgradeable_mutex::state::aspiring
>
() {
  s.unlock();
}
template<>
void upgradeable_mutex::transition_down<
  upgradeable_mutex::state::aspiring, upgradeable_mutex::state::shared
>
() {
  s.lock();
  u.unlock();
}
  void upgradeable_mutex::lock() {
    transition_up<state::unlocked, state::unique>();
  }
  void upgradeable_mutex::unlock() {
    transition_down<state::unique, state::unlocked>();
  }
  void upgradeable_mutex::lock_shared() {
    transition_up<state::unlocked, state::shared>();
  }
  void upgradeable_mutex::unlock_shared() {
    transition_down<state::shared, state::unlocked>();
  }
  void upgradeable_mutex::lock_aspiring() {
    transition_up<state::unlocked, state::aspiring>();
  }
  void upgradeable_mutex::unlock_aspiring() {
    transition_down<state::aspiring, state::unlocked>();
  }
  void upgradeable_mutex::aspiring_to_unique() {
    transition_up<state::aspiring, state::unique>();
  }
  void upgradeable_mutex::unique_to_aspiring() {
    transition_down<state::unique, state::aspiring>();
  }
  void upgradeable_mutex::aspiring_to_shared() {
    transition_down<state::aspiring, state::shared>();
  }
  void upgradeable_mutex::unique_to_shared() {
    transition_down<state::unique, state::shared>();
  }
```

I attempt to get the compiler to work out some of the above transitions "for me" with the `transition_up` and `transition_down` trick.  I think I can do better, and it did increase code bulk significantly.

Having it 'auto-write' the unlocked-to-unique, and unique-to-(unlocked|shared) was all I got out of it.  So probably not worth it.

Creating smart RAII objects that use the above is a bit tricky, as they have to support some transitions that the default `unique_lock` and `shared_lock` do not support.

You could just write `aspiring_lock` and then do conversions in there (either as `operator unique_lock`, or as methods that return said, etc), but the ability to convert from `unique_lock&&` down to `shared_lock` is exclusive to upgradeable_mutex and is a bit tricky to work with implicit conversions...

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67dbfad540607322).

Comment: After a `U->R` transition the state is "no lock held," but the desired state is `read(A)`.  I can't decide where the type-o is.

Comment: I _think_ the correction should be: `U->R = read(A) then unlock(B)`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant yep -- sorry, I have two versions of this.  One holds a read lock as well as a "upgrade" lock in the upgrade state, another only holds the upgrade lock.  I changed my mind on which I was working on and missed a transition.  D'oh.

Comment: Nice!  I've built on what you have and I can now also see `W->R`, `try-R->U` and `try-R->W`. :-)

Comment: @HowardHinnant By `try-R->W` you mean `try` `R->W`, heh, I misread that. `R->try W`?

Comment: Yes, I meant `try` `R->W`.  Try to upgrade from shared to exclusive.

Comment: Using `U` seems pretty similar to `upgrade_lock` in _Boost_ (which is not applicable - see other answer). Sadly as a result, this is missing the `R->U` transition, which I require.

Comment: @abergmeier Is there a reason you think that transition is *possible* without transactional code or deadlocks?  If you have two simultaneous read locks that want to upgrade to write, you are mandating the code deadlocks, as *neither* can progress while the other is waiting.  Transactional code is code that can be completely undone (so you can roll back one read to the unlocked unread state, advance the other read to write, finish that write, then repeat the read).

Comment: @Yakk Well we do by now have some internal transition code, which might work without transactional code and hopefully without deadlocks ;). That being said we need to track **way** more state and it is not that "lightweight" anymore. Will post once we validated, that it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my usual suggestion: [Seqlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seqlock)

You can have a single writer and many readers concurrently. Writers compete using a spinlock. A single writer doesn't need to compete so is cheaper.

Readers are truly only reading. They're not writing any state variables, counters, etc. This means you don't really know how many readers are there. But also, there no cache line ping pong so you get the best performance possible in terms of latency and throughput.

What's the catch? the data almost has to be POD. It doesn't really have to POD, but it can not be invalidated (no deleting std::map nodes) as readers may read it while it's being written.

It's only after the fact that readers discover the data is possibly bad and they have to re-read.

Yes, writers don't wait for readers so there's no concept of upgrade/downgrade. You can unlock one and lock the other. You pay less than with any sort of mutex but the data may have changed in the process.

I can go into more detail if you like.

Answer (score 1):

The [`std::shared_mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex) (as implemented in [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.upgrade_mutex) if not available on your platform(s)) provides some alternative for the problem.

For atomic upgrade lock semantics, the boost [upgrade lock](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.locks.upgrade_lock) may be the best cross platform alternative.

It does not have an upgrade and downgrade locking mechanism you are looking for, but to get an exclusive lock, the shared access can be relinquished first, then exclusive access sought.

```
// assumes shared_lock with shared access has been obtained
ReadContainerLock container = state.getContainer();
auto value = container.find( "foo" )->bar;
{
  container.shared_mutex().unlock();
  // Upgrade read lock to write lock
  std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> write(container.shared_mutex());
  // container work...
  write.unlock();
  container.shared_mutex().lock_shared();
} // Downgrades write lock to read lock
```

A utility class can be used to cause the re-locking of the `shared_mutex` at the end of the scope;

```
struct re_locker {
  re_locker(std::shared_mutex& m) : m_(m) { m_.unlock(); }
  ~re_locker() { m_.shared_lock(); }
  // delete the copy and move constructors and assignment operator (redacted for simplicity)
};
// ...
auto value = container.find( "foo" )->bar;
{
  re_locker re_lock(container.shared_mutex());
  // Upgrade read lock to write lock
  std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> write(container.shared_mutex());
  // container work...
} // Downgrades write lock to read lock
```

Depending on what exception guarantees you want or require, you may need to add a "can re-lock" flag to the `re_locker` to either do the re-lock or not if an exception is thrown during the container operations/work.

Comment: Without upgrade and downgrade, the locking operations are not atomic and thus useless for my scenario. Sorry.

Comment: @abergmeier. The boost upgrade lock may be worth a look; http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_concepts.upgrade_lockable

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.locks.upgrade_lock

Comment: I did look at the `upgrade_lock`. The problem is that since there can only be a single `upgrade_lock` at a time, it cannot be efficiently used when most of the code paths need to upgrade eventually.

Comment: @abergmeier, in the question you said writes are rare, so how why "most of the code paths need to upgrade eventually"?

Comment: @BitWhistler The need to upgrade is mostly to keep the state across function calls as consistent as possible. Even with that conservative approach we see some strange side effects, as you would expect from a large codebase.

Comment: @abergmeier, I don't follow. I don't think I understand what's "consistent state" in your terminology as it sounds too much like everything is serialized, so might as well run on a single core... which I guess can not be the case.